# Mysql module not found in google cloud

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, mysql-connector

I am having trouble connecting to mysql in a python Flask app through google cloud.

My app works locally. I run the app on `localhost`, I submit a web form, and the contents are uploaded to the mysql database that I have running on AWS.

For `DB_HOST`, `DB_PASS`, etc, I have these in a `.env` file, and I load them, along with my other packages, as

```
from flask import Flask, render_tempalate, request
from jinja1 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os 
from dotenv import load_dotenv 
import mysql.connector

load_dotenv()
```

When I tried to upload the app to google cloud through `gcloud app deploy`, it gave me the error

```
   from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
[2024-01-22 15:17:50 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
[2024-01-22 15:17:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2024-01-22 15:17:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I commented out `from dotenv...` and `load_dotenv()`, and stored the environment variables for the MySQL connection in google cloud itself. Now my imports look like this

```
from flask import Flask, render_tempalate, request
from jinja1 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os 
# from dotenv import load_dotenv 
import mysql.connector

# load_dotenv()
```

I redeployed the app to google cloud, and then received this error

```
...
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
...
```

I am confused because I have a `mysql` package within an `env` folder that google cloud created for me. I started the project with a simple web tutorial on google cloud.

Also, when I run `pip install mysql-connector-python` it returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (8.3.0)
```

I researched MySQL on google cloud and it was using a lot of `sqlalchemy`, though I'm not familiar with this, and I'd prefer to use `mysql.connector` if possible.

I'm calling the database as

```
dataBase = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=os.environ['DB_HOST'], 
    ...
```

then

```
def saveData(args)
    query = "..."
    vals = (...)
    cursorObject = dataBase.cursor() 
    cursorObject.execute(query, vals) 
    ...
```

My `app.yaml` file is

```
runtime: python 
env: flex 
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app 

runtime_config: 
   operating_system: ubuntu22

manual_scaling:
  instance: 1 
resources: 
  cpu: 1 
  memory_gb: 0.5 
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

My `.gitignore` file is

```
.env 
.env*local
```

My `requirements.txt` is

```
Flask==3.0.0; python_version > '3.6'
Flask==2.3.3; python_version < '3.7'
Werkzeug==3.0.1; python_version > '3.6'
Werkzeug==2.3.7; python_version < '3.7'
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

My `gcloud` version is

```
Google Cloud SDK 460.0.0
bq 2.0.101
core 2021.01.12
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.27
```

My directory structure is

```
myproject
|
|--env
|   |
|   +--Include
|   +--Lib
|   |   |
|   |   +site-packages
|   |        |...
|   |        +--mysql
|   |
|   +--Scripts
|   +--pyvenv.cfg
|
|--static
|--templates
|--.env 
|--.flaskenv 
|--.gitignore
|--app.yaml
|--main.py
|--requirements.txt
```

Anyways thank you for any help.

Comment: Edit your question and include the contents of `.gitignore` and `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Yes, I realize I needed to update `requirements.txt`. Thank you @JohnHanley

Answer (score 0):

I realize I needed to update `requirements.txt`. This is what installs the package on a different system than my own.

Now my `requirements.txt` is

```
Flask==3.0.0; python_version > '3.6'
Flask==2.3.3; python_version < '3.7'
Werkzeug==3.0.1; python_version > '3.6'
Werkzeug==2.3.7; python_version < '3.7'
gunicorn==20.1.0
mysql-connector-python==8.3.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
```

and I uncommented `from dotenv import load_dotenv` and `load_dotenv()`. My full import statement is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import mysql.connector
```

My `pyvenv.cfg` file is

```
home = C:\Python310
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.10.7
```

Now it works!